# Link_to another view ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I am trying to use the link_to feature to link one view to another.

The view i am calling link_to is app/views/instructors/show.html.erb and that snippet of code looks like this (namely, the second to last line of it)

```
<% provide(:title, @instructor.login) %>
<% courses = Course.where(:instructor_ID => @instructor.id) %>
    <div class="span2">
      <h1 align=center ><%= @instructor.login %></h1>
      <%= link_to "Add course", new_course_path(:instructor_ID\
                => @instructor.id), :class => "btn" %>
        <br>
        <br>
        <%= link_to "Remove course", delete_course_path(courses), :class => "btn"%>
    </div>
```

The view I am trying to link to is is app/views/courses/show_all.html.erb and looks like this:

```
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= course.course_name %></td>
    <td><%= course.instructor_ID %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', course %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_course_path(course) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', course, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
```

delete_course_path routes to app/views/courses/show_all.html.erb shown above.  When I try the code above, I get the following error:

> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

At this line:

```
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
```

Any ideas what i'm missing in my link_to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `show_all` action, you should define a `@courses` instance variables. This is

`<% courses = Course.where(:instructor_ID => @instructor.id) %>`

not passed to `show_all.html.erb`.

An instance variables is a variable passed from action of controller to the view corresponding.

I suppose when you show page of instructor, your route will like this: `/instructors/:id`, so maybe in your show_all action of instructor controller, you need something like:

```
def show_all
  @courses = Course.where(instructor_ID: params[:id])
  render 'courses/show_all'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that `@courses` is nil. Did you set it in your `show_all` action of your controller? E.g.

```
def show_all
  @courses = Course.all
end
```

Also, in your `show` view, you set `courses` to a collection of `Course` objects, but your "Remove course" link looks like you only want to delete one course. Why do you use the `delete_course` route to link to your show_all view?

Comment: Thanks that worked.  Pardon my lack of knowledge on the topic but does that mean that every view needs a controller method to go along with it?

Comment: In most cases, there should be a controller method for each view. By using the `render` method in a controller action you can specify another view to be rendered, though. Or redirect to another page, see the scaffolded delete, update or create methods of the controller for example.